# Notice (8): Undefined variable cakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

After many hours of searching in Net I decided to post my question here hoping to find the solution

Here is my code in my View `add_by_complex.ctp` :

```html
<div class="immeubles form large-10 medium-9 columns content">
  <?= $this->Form->create($immeuble); /* line 9 */ ?>
    <fieldset>
      <legend><?= __('Ajouter un immeuble') ?></legend>
      <?php echo $this->Form->input('name',['label' => 'Nom']); ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Valider')) ?>
  <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

Here is the error message :

> Notice (8): Undefined variable: immeuble 
> [APP/Template\Immeubles\add_by_complex.ctp, line 9]

What is the problem? thanks lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating forms with a context, you will have to provide an Entity or ArrayContext to the `create()` method form.

> The $model argument is used as the form’s ‘context’. There are several built-in form contexts and you can add your own, which we’ll cover in the next section. The built-in providers map to the following values of $model:

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#starting-a-form

If you do not provide any parameters, it will assume that you are building just a form that submits to the controller.

To be able to access the Entity, or any other, variable in a View you'll have to [set the View variable](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#setting-view-variables)

Comment: thanks for your answer.I Have an Entity called 'Immeuble.php' in Model/Entity
what intrigues me is that I  have the same code in add.ctp and it works fine      

<div class="immeubles form large-10 medium-9 columns content">
    <?= $this->Form->create($immeuble) ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Add Immeuble') ?></legend>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('complex_id', ['options' => $complexes]);
            echo $this->Form->input('name');
        
        ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>

Comment: The code in the view is just fine, you're only missing the `$this->set('immeuble',$immeuble)` in this controller.

Comment: Pb solved , thanks a lot Sevvlor for your time and your help :)